# Calling multiple partially chained requests in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Being very new to Scrapy I am struggling to parse data from API the way I want. My current code looks like this:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['main_url'] = response.url
    item['company_data'] = response.text
    item['statements'] = []
    item['reports'] = []

    response_json = json.loads(response.text)

    if 'statements' in response_json:
        statement_ids = response_json['statements']
        request = Request(STATEMENT_URL+str(statement_ids.pop(0)), callback=self.statement_parse)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        request.meta['statement_ids'] = statement_ids
        yield request

    if 'reports' in response_json:
        report_ids = response_json['reports']
        request = Request(REPORT_URL+str(report_ids.pop(0)), callback=self.report_parse)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        request.meta['report_ids'] = report_ids
        yield request

def statement_parse(self, response):
    statement_ids = response.meta['statement_ids']
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['statements'].append(response.text)
    if not statement_ids:
        yield item
    url = STATEMENT_URL+str(statement_ids.pop(0))
    request = Request(url, callback=self.statement_parse)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    request.meta['statement_ids'] = statement_ids
    yield request

def report_parse(self, response):
    report_ids = response.meta['report_ids']
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['reports'].append(response.text)
    if not report_ids:
        yield item
    url = REPORT_URL+str(report_ids.pop(0))
    request = Request(url, callback=self.report_parse)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    request.meta['report_ids'] = report_ids
    yield request
```

Both keys that I look for in the `response_json` return an array of ids. If either of them (or both) exist I want to call the appropriate url with every returned id and save json responses into my scrapy item.

Even though I understand why my current code is not working as I expect, I can't figure out how to achieve what I want.

Comment: in function statement_parse you have "if not statement_ids: yield item
" is it possible that in the next line  "statement_ids.pop(0)" can throw error ?

Comment: @woblob it doesn't throw an error. Actually this snippet works, the problem is that scrapy returns two identical items instead of one when both keys exist in `response_json` (because both yields in `parse` are triggered).

Comment: You can either learn to use Scrapy callbacks and the `cb_kwargs` and `meta` parameters of requests, or you use the `scrapy-inline-requests` plugin to write code more similar to what you already have.